# Does partition splitting happens when partition has a local secondary index?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Partition splitting happens in two conditions:
  1.Increased Provisioned Throughput Settings,
  2.Increased Storage Requirements.

> If an item collection exceeds the 10 GB limit, DynamoDB will return an ItemCollectionSizeLimitExceededException and you won't be able to add more items to the item collection or increase the sizes of items that are in the item collection.

This means in second condition, partitionsplitting will never happen. Does this imply the same in first condition too?

Comment: In quote and after it, the partition means a partition which has a local secondary index. It's different from the partion in first line!

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 - Partition split under increased provisioned throughput - If the application crosses the threshold limit then we can make a 'special request' to AWS to increase the throughput.

This condition is encounted only in the 'managed service of DynamoDB' and NOT if you install dynamodb locally.